# depthimage_to_laserscan not publishing

Tags: gmapping, ros-noetic

I am running node using

```
rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan image:=/depth_image
```

where `/depth_image` is a topic in the bag file I am playing, when using `echo` on `/scan` it shows nothing. Also, is a launch file necessary in this case? Also, if I set camera info I get `code exit -11` which I think corresponds to segmentatiom fault.
I am using ROS Noetic on Ubuntu  20.04.

Answer (score 0):

I have already worked with this package. I would debug in this way:

1- First check if you are sending data from your camera

```
rostopic echo /depth_image
```

2 - It is very important that you also send the configuration data of your camera. Just check if you are publishing a **camera_info** topic or not

```
rostopic list | grep camera_info
```

3- open rqt_graph and check which node is not receiving or not publishing data correctly into a topic

```
rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph
```

In ROS2 I had a similar issue described here: https://answers.ros.org/question/417736/depth_image_to_laserscan-not-publishing-to-kinect_scan-topic-in-ros2-galactic/?answer=417845#post-id-417845

For my case however the solution was changing the reliability quality of service (QoS), but I think in ROS1 this is not needed correct?

4- After check the rqt_graph and introspect the node/topic which are or are not sending/receiving data , you will have a clear understanding of what is wrong. If the names of expected topics to subscribe/publish be wrong, you can remap the topics to match the names you need. For example:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="depthimage_to_laserscan" type="depthimage_to_laserscan_node" name="depthimage_to_laserscan">
    <remap from="image" to="/depth_image"/>
    <!-- Add any other necessary remappings or parameter settings here -->
  </node>
</launch>
```

5- Use **rostopic info 'topic name'** and/or **rosnode info 'node_name'** cmds to get more insights of what the node/topic are supposed to publish and to consume (subscribe) to check what is working and what is not matching.

Just take a look at the documentation (I forgot) what are the prerequisites and expected topics required to subscribe and publish? I know that calibration parameters to feed the camera_info topic are also needed (usually a .yaml file on param folder or directly declared in launch file).